# Manipulating with Date function

Tags: php

So, I want to create some kind of "timer" which will depend on the current time of the system + some more days/months. So basically my code is:

```
<?php
$CurrentDate=Date('d:m:y');
$NewDate=Date('d:m:y', strtotime('+3 days'));
if($CurrentDate==$newDate){
echo "We're open today!";
}
elseif($CurrentDate>$newDate){
echo "You're late";
}
else{
echo "X more days to go !";
}
?>
```

I get that $CurrentDate will never be equal to $NewDate because they change simultaneously together but I want to set $CurrentDate to static somehow so it wont change and it will "wait" for the $newDate;
Thank you everyone.

Comment: You'll need to use a db for this..or alternatively store new date in a file

Comment: Actually yes, it worked as you suggested. I used a db which contains a table with a column with the current date and then I used php to do the other work. I used this code:
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$k=Date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 days'));
which works pretty good I think, it will take 3 days till it gets equally with the date in the db. Thank you very much for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help...