# Show text after a date has passed

Tags: php

I am trying to get a simple line of text to appear if todays date is after another date.

I can either get it to appear on all pages or none, but I am unable to get it to display based on whether the challenge start date is before or after todays date. I believe it could be a date format issue, but everything I have tried has fallen short.

Here is my code:

**Get todays date**

```php
$date_now = new dateTime();
```

**Challenge start date**

```php
$challengeStartDate = date('dS F Y', strtotime($this->item->start_date));
echo '<!--' . strtotime('1970/1/1 00:00:00 +' . $validity) . '-->';
```

**New text line**

```php
if ($challengeStartDate > $date_now) echo "New Text";
```

Comment: You can test against `time()`, see my answer below

Comment: "I believe it could be a date format issue" - Definitively, converting dates to text is not going to help with maths. Choose a format (Unix time or DateTime objects), stick to it and don't convert to human-readable strings until you want to display it to end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) returns a string. With `$challengeStartDate > $date_now` it's like comparing if one string is bigger than the other (not sure if your `dateTime` handles that).

Your approach is otherwise fine. Just use timestamps to compare. [time()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) gets you the time as a Unix timestamp:

```php
$now = time();
if ($now > strtotime($this->item->start_date)) {
  // do your thing
}
```

Something like this is more what you need. Try it out.

Comment: HI both, really appreciate the help. Peter, I have added the code as you explained.   <?php if ($now > $this->item->start_date).  but the text is still showing on all pages, even is the start date is in the future on some of those pages. If I reverse the $now < then it appears on none of them. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well that is the `$this->item->start_date` value exactly? For example `time() > time() - 1` is definitely true. When the `start_date` is in the past, the if statement will be true.

Comment: Ah I see now, I needed to add a `strtotime()` like in your code.. try out my updated answer.

Comment: Thats the one, perfect. I really appreciate your assistance in this.

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help 

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem some time ago.
All you need to do is store your local time in a database so it would be saved statically.
Because in your example, both `$challengeStartDate` and `$date_now` will change and update simultaneously and you wiill always get the current pc time!
Try storing it in a table or idk maybe sessions would help too.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67153764/manipulating-with-date-function) post. Read the comments also. It really helped me.

Comment: The OP pulls the time to compare from `$this->item->start_date`. Seems it is already coming from the database.

Comment: Well, if so than I don't see a reason why it is not working. 
Basically it goes like "This is today's date, but if today's date is  +1 hour then show me some text".
So  `if(  $datenow > $this->item>start_date) echo 'working';`

Comment: I have an idea. See my answer.

Comment: Sorry I can't comment on your answer. But I think you are right, that seems the legit way to achieve that.